# How to update PHP syntax file for vim?

Tags: macvim

I notice the syntax file for PHP for vim is quite out-dated.
Does anyone know where is these syntax file located in Mac so I can do the upgrade?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved myself,
here are the steps :-

1. `locate vim | grep php`
2. turn up is this file `/usr/share/vim/vim73/syntax/php.vim`
3. `sudo mv /usr/share/vim/vim73/syntax/php.vim /usr/share/vim/vim73/autoload/phpcomplete.vim.orig` as backup
4. download latest php vim file from http://www.vim.org
5. untar the tarball
6. copy the php.vim to /usr/share/vim/vim73/syntax/php.vim

Answer (score -1):

I think the proper solution is to install the updated syntax file locally, in your `~/.vim/syntax` directory.
From your answer, you have installed the syntax file in `/usr/share/vim`, which is system class directory. This is not recommended since this can be erased on system or application update, and you don't know what your modification might conflict with. Instead, you should put all your vim configuration files under your home directory in `~/.vim`.

(Sorry if it isn't a proper answer to your problem, but it seems I can't add comment to already posted answers)

Comment: which exactly i already did

Comment: It seems to me what you did is quite a different approach: directly modifying the system version of the file in `/usr/share/vim`. Please reread my answer to understand why it is not the proper way to override the default syntax file.

If you look a possibly up to date syntax file, I suggest you take a look at [StanAngeloff's php syntax plugin](https://github.com/StanAngeloff/php.vim) (or better, if you use many languages: the [vim-polyglot plugin](https://github.com/sheerun/vim-polyglot)).